# Proxy-Authorization: <type> <credentials>?

Tags: html, http

I'm sending an HTTP request to a server through a proxy with request authentication "Basic". It's a squid proxy. I want to send an HTTP request containing the auth within the headers field. Taking my example:

```
GET /text.html/ HTTP/1.1
Host: http://Jb.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

Through a proxy say `my.proxy.com:8080` but auth is needed say "john:qwerty". 
How can I put this auth within the request header?

Comment: How are you sending the request?

Comment: Vasan ,am sending the request over an injection tool ,which works perfectly well,without including proxy-authorization:  and i listen to the connection via browser it returns the 407 login required,however I want to give someone the same program but without them bothering with login prompts

Answer (score 0):

Sending credentials to a server behind a proxy is the same of sending them directly to the server.

Basic authentication is contained into `Proxy-Authorization` header, as a base64-encoded colon-separated username and password.

I am assuming that you want to manually craft the authorization value.
 Follow these steps (given username `john` and password `qwerty`):

1. Join username and password with a colon: `john:qwerty`
2. Base64-encode the whole string: `am9objpxd2VydHk=`
3. Put the encoded string into the `Proxy-Authorization` header. Append this to your HTTP request: `Proxy-Authorization: Basic am9objpxd2VydHk=`

This should work out of the box with the majority of proxy servers.

Comment: thankyou Mario Cianciolo let me do as you have said and will give feedback as soon as possible

Comment: Actually the correct header for your needs is `Proxy-Authorization`, my mistake, I'm editing the answer. The full process is documented [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Proxy-Authorization)

Comment: Ok I have seen the adjustments

Comment: Thankyou very much its working very fine extremely,Mario Cianciolo thanks a lot,I really needed this working

Comment: If this worked for you, please upvote my answer and mark it as the correct answer :)